# Portable AC unit extraction hose routing

Tags: air-conditioning, hose, portable-ac

I've got a "portable AC unit"  which is a free-standing unit, not a permanent installation like a high wall split system.

They require to be vented to the outside world, otherwise they simply don't work.  I intend to use this to cool down my garage/workshop which has no normal windows.

**What is the best way to vent this AC unit?**

The options are :

1. Run the large diameter spiral hose straight up, and over the brick wall, then down through a soffit vent.
2. Same, but tee the hose into an existing extractor fan's hose (for venting a laundry space, rarely used)
3. Same, but simply run the hose into the roof cavity and let it heat an already hot space.

Drilling a vent:

- through the wall is not easy because its brick-lined on the outside
- through the person-door is impossible because its entirely double glazed and opens back against a wall
- through the car door is unfeasible because it moves up and down
- through the roofing will break the waterproof layer, and I'd rather not.

[image: Dimplex portable AC]

Comment: I don't yet have any condensate coming from the unit, but its dry here now so this may increase later on.

Comment: Not sure what you *should* do, but definitely don't "**Same, but simply run the hose into the roof cavity and let it heat an already hot space.**"

Comment: remove a brick from the wall and vent there.

Answer (score 2):

How about opening the garage door by 6", running the hose under the door, then building a wood & foam (for some insulation) blocker to cover the rest of the opening?

You can make an appropriate sized hole in your blocker to hold the hose in place, it vents directly outside *without* cooking your attic space, and you can run the condensate hose through it with its own little opening, too.

If you don't have some sort of lift-up door (you said garage, I assumed that you *could* park a car in there), make a vertical blocker that fits into the "people" door. Swing the people door open, put the blocker in place (with a wedge top & bottom to close off the angle left by the swing-open door), latch the door closed against a stop (top, bottom & latch side) that you install on the stopper, and brace the stopper against the wall. i.e. build a portable door jamb designed to hold the door open just enough to allow the vent hose to run through it, but otherwise insulated enough to keep the heat out and the cool in.

With a proper strike plate, the door retains its full utility, though the opening may be slightly narrower when installed. When you're done working, remove the blocker and close/lock the door as you normally would for security.

Comment: That was definitely a possibility, though the better-3/4 was concerned with aesthetics.  My  very-longterm plan is to build another freestanding shed as workshop and do it properly, leaving the attached garage for storage and cars only.  But money :-\

Answer (score 0):

Update - my temporary install has been a 6" hose straight up through a manhole in the ceiling.

I've used some old suspended ceiling tiles to block the manhole other than a 6" hole for the hose.   This admittedly rough solution knocks ~5 degrees off the room temperature, but sadly does vent straight into the roof space.

For the condensate hose, I drilled a 6.5mm hole through the plastic and brought it out the side into a spare 1.5L PET bottle.  So far there has been zero water in the catch bottle.

The next plan is to get more hose and join the ceiling panel to an existing soffit vent - I temporarily reallocated the ceiling vent from a laundry, which we never used.

Was it worth doing?  Had I paid full price for this thing, definitely not.   But it was quite cheap at $74 NZ so it seems adequate to cap the temperatures.

This would have been so much easier if the target room had a window.

Comment: Don't vent in to the attic, even with a condensate drain. Those AC units put the condensate tray in the path of the hot exhaust, and even with an open drain you will get significant humidity in the hot exhaust.

Comment: @longneck there is a condensate hose - about 8mm OD and 6mm ID.  By design its supposed to route along the air tube and out a window, but I've brought it out the side of the hose and dropped into a bottle instead.     There's never been any water in it, the workshop doesn't have many sources of dampness.

Comment: I understand that there is a hose, but those AC units put condensate in to the hot exhaust. There's a reason you're not seeing anything in the bottle: it's going in to your attic.

Comment: @longneck so what's the point of the little hose at all ?

Comment: Inside the air conditioner, the condensate drips in front of the fan that pushes out there hot air. Any water that doesn't get immediately evaporated and sent out the exhaust drops in to a tray. The water in that tray evaporates on it's own from the ambient air temperature, and newer models have a little paddle wheel that throws water from the tray in front of the exhaust fan. The little hose connects to the tray, but in low humidity environments all the water gets exhausted before the tray fills up enough to exit through the hose.